# How to insert binary data in Postgres oid column

Tags: postgresql

I have following query

```
 INSERT INTO SESSIONINFO(ID, LASTMODIFICATIONDATE, RULESBYTEARRAY, STARTDATE) VALUES 
(1, NULL, '\xaced0005774d0a060805100418005243080010001a3918002000320608011000180042121a080a044d41494e100022060a044d41494e52090a0744454641554c545a0c0a0a0805320608001000180122026800')
```

When i try to  execute above statement getting following error

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type oid: "\xaced0005774d0a060805100418005243080010001a3918002000320608011000180042121a080a044d41494e100022060a044d41494e52090a0744454641554c545a0c0a0a0805320608001000180122026800"
```

How to solve this..

Answer (score 1):

I think you've confused `oid` and `bytea`.

`bytea` is used for binary data in a row. Your `RULESBYTEARRAY` column should almost certainly have `bytea` as its type. See [binary data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) in the manual.

The `oid` column type is a simple 32-bit unsigned integer. It's used by PostgreSQL to refer to system tables and all sorts of other things. One of the uses is to refer to rows in the [`pg_largeobject`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-largeobject.html) table, which can be used to store file-like objects.

If you want to store and retrieve binary data you almost certainly want to use `bytea`-typed fields, not `pg_largeobject`. `pg_largobject` is intended for very, very big data and/or data that you want to read and modify without having to load the whole lot each time and write it all back again whenever you change anything.

Answer (score 1):

To insert into column of type oid you can use [lo_from_bytea](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/lo-funcs.html) function:

> Create a large object and store data there, returning its OID. Pass 0 to have the system choose an OID.

So in your example:

```
INSERT INTO SESSIONINFO(ID, LASTMODIFICATIONDATE, RULESBYTEARRAY, STARTDATE) VALUES 
(1, NULL, lo_from_bytea(0, '\xaced0005774d0a060805100418005243080010001a3918002000320608011000180042121a080a044d41494e100022060a044d41494e52090a0744454641554c545a0c0a0a0805320608001000180122026800'))
```